# Add a url when data is not found

Tags: jquery

Chosen-select allows to display text when data is not found. Is it possible to show a link to go to another page instead of the text when data is not found?

```
  <select  class="form-control chosen-select"  multiple  name="seguro_medico[]" >

  <?php 

   foreach($seguro_medico as $row)
  { 
  echo '<option value="'.$row->id_sm.'">'.$row->title.'</option>';
  }
  ?>

  </select>

   //js

  $(".chosen-select").chosen({
 no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found : "
 })
```

How can i add a link instead of the text ?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

you need to do this in php based on how you're populating your select.

```
<?php if ( count( $seguro_medico) == 0) {
?>
<a href='a link'>this is a link</a>
<?php
} else {
 <select  class="form-control chosen-select"  multiple  name="seguro_medico[]" >

  <?php 
   foreach($seguro_medico as $row)
  { 
  echo '<option value="'.$row->id_sm.'">'.$row->title.'</option>';
  }
  ?>

  </select>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Hmm, i still don't understand your codes. Do i have to wrap them in $(".chosen-select").chosen({ -------}) ?

Comment: yes the code is sloppy. i'm at work and don't have time to format it better.

Comment: I tried your answer it keeps showing me the text: noting found. When there is not data. I also try to put a link like this :<option><a href="link"> link</a></option> and the php code down side. It's not clickable.

Comment: I find a new way to do that. But i'm going to post a new issue. Thanks for your time

Comment: please upvote or mark this answer correct if you want to thank me for my time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160216/discussion-between-diasline-and-catbadger).